# Same code behave differently on two servers

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my localhost and one server is all right, array has the same values within console inside $.each function like outside, but on another server that code behave differently. Second console return empty array, inside it is correct. How can server change client-side language behaviour?

```
var isChecked = [];
$('.x').each(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    id = $(this).prop('id').split('_')[1];
    isChecked.push(id);
    console.log(isChecked);
  } else {
    isChecked.splice($.inArray(id, isChecked), 1);
  }
});
console.log(isChecked);
```

Markup is:

```
<table>
  <tr class=header>
    <td class=first>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c">
      <label for="c"><span class="tablecheck"></span></label>
    </td>
    <td class="header" colspan=""><a href="/">User group</a></td>
    <td class="header" colspan=""><a href="/">Firstname</a></td>
    <td class="header" colspan="2"><a href="/">Lastname</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td class=first>
      <input type="checkbox" id="x_41" class="x">
      <label for="x_41"><span class="tablecheck"></span></label>
    </td>
    <td>Admin</td>
    <td>Firstname</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It can't. Show us your markup?

Comment: The code looks fine, can you point us to a live example? Have you tested it with different browsers?

Comment: Given the above code, if the output is different, the markup is different.

Comment: I inserted markup, but I can't show live version (client's wish). And yes I tested in the same browser (FF) on the same computer.

Comment: Server can't change client-side behaviour. There has to be more to this problem. Voting to close on the grounds that this is impossible. Sorry you can't provide a demo, but there's nothing top secret about this code.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I thing that it is clear to everyone ... but I tried it many times and different option is not possible too:). No there is not, but project is much more bigger and my contract that prohibits.

Comment: As @WesleyMurch stated there has to be more to this - server cant change client behaviour, it only serves data to the client. Check all included JS files etc. Debug in JS console clientside.

Comment: @rootkit I did everything what you say, but nothing find.

Answer (score 0):

> How can server change client-side language behaviour?

I would guess your browser has cached an older version of the JavaScript file from the second server, which would explain why you are seeing different behavior.